# Paypal integration in responsive website

Tags: php, paypal

I used below code for payment integration

```
<form id = "paypal_checkout" action = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method = "post">
    <input name = "cmd" value = "_cart" type = "hidden">
    <input name = "upload" value = "1" type = "hidden">
    <input name = "no_note" value = "0" type = "hidden">
    <input name = "bn" value = "PP-BuyNowBF" type = "hidden">
    <input name = "tax" value = "0" type = "hidden">
    <input name = "rm" value = "2" type = "hidden">

    <input name = "business" value = "xxxxxxxx" type = "hidden">
    <input name = "handling_cart" value = "0" type = "hidden">
    <input name = "currency_code" value = "GBP" type = "hidden">
    <input name = "lc" value = "GB" type = "hidden">
    <input name = "return" value = "http://mysite/myreturnpage" type = "hidden">
    <input name = "cbt" value = "Return to My Site" type = "hidden">
    <input name = "cancel_return" value = "http://mysite/mycancelpage" type = "hidden">
    <input name = "custom" value = "" type = "hidden">

    <div id = "item_1" class = "itemwrap">
        <input name = "item_name_1" value = "Gold Tickets" type = "hidden">
        <input name = "quantity_1" value = "4" type = "hidden">
        <input name = "amount_1" value = "30" type = "hidden">
        <input name = "shipping_1" value = "0" type = "hidden">
    </div>
    <div id = "item_2" class = "itemwrap">
        <input name = "item_name_2" value = "Silver Tickets" type = "hidden">
        <input name = "quantity_2" value = "2" type = "hidden">
        <input name = "amount_2" value = "20" type = "hidden">
        <input name = "shipping_2" value = "0" type = "hidden">
    </div>
    <div id = "item_3" class = "itemwrap">
        <input name = "item_name_3" value = "Bronze Tickets" type = "hidden">
        <input name = "quantity_3" value = "2" type = "hidden">
        <input name = "amount_3" value = "15" type = "hidden">
        <input name = "shipping_3" value = "0" type = "hidden">
    </div>

     <input id = "ppcheckoutbtn" value = "Checkout" class = "button" type = "submit">
</form>
```

This code is working fine but i have problem in responsive design of paypal screens

**My question**

1. How to develop responsive paypal screens for payment integration

Comment: you mean on your own website how to make the page responsive?

Comment: @Shehary No when i pay in mobile device the paypal screens are not responsive

Comment: you need express checkout, with express checkout you can make paypal payment page responsive but with paypal standard, payment page can't be responsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, PayPal standard payment buttons are responsive in its nature, but there're certain use cases that will not be supported on a mobile device, see [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/mobile-paypal-payments-standard/) for details (Section of "Unsupported Use Cases"), and in your case, the add to cart button will not adapt into a mobile screen.

While Express Checkout, as an API integration sulotion, will be more mobile-friendily, and supporting most of the payment use cases to be adapted on a mobile experience.
Please check the [Demo Portal](https://demo.paypal.com/us/home) for some insights to help with your integration

Comment: Thank you so much PP_pduan for your help!!!I solved this issue by the link what you have sent!! I struggled to solve this issue for more than 5 days. cheers!